# Geoserver and PostGis output

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver

I have a peculiar rendering of a small table in PostGis of polygones (imported from a shape file) from Geoserver (layer preview with OpenLayers)

[image: Default view when clicking on the layer preview from GeoServer admin]

[image: Zoomed in]

The object are just cloned ... Would you give me a clue on what is going on ?

Here is the output of the same table using QGis

[image]

Comment: what projection is your data in? and what did you tell GeoServer it was in?

Comment: I am wondering why this question was closed for being unclear. It is quite a nasty trend on Stack Exchanges those days ... To cancel questions for being not clear, not fitting some obscure rules ... For the question is a part of the problem...

Comment: My guess is that I asked you to clarify in October and nothing had happened by the end of December, so it looked like an orphan question

Comment: @iant All right. I get it. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally happens because of the data in geoserver is in projected system and you try to access it using geodetic system.

Comment: I feel this should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: I have edited the answer.